# Get gdx game to draw below the notch on android devices

Tags: libgdx

I generated a new game using the gdx project generator (gdx-setup.jar), which uses gdx 1.12.1. The android version of the app doesn't draw below the notch on my test devices, it leaves a black strip there. Is there a way to get the game to draw below the notch?

Below is the auto generated styles.xml. I cannot find the right config to get the app to draw below the notch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/ic_background_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I tried create a wizard-generated android project using Android Studio to copy its `Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar` theme but appears to have no effect (requires using Material theme, etc)

```
...

<style name="Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```